# How to filter information from an output that consists of "X": "Y",

Tags: javascript, json, filter, node-red

I'm working with NodeRed and using a Twitter node. I'm trying to figure out how to reply to users if they tweet 'X'.

The output consists of a load of information all comma separated and all consist of "x": "y",

As in
`"User": "SanderSchaeffer", "Tweet": "This is my tweet", "date": "01-02-2015",` etc.

How would I filter, preferably with Javascript or JSON, just the information that is contained by "user"? So the output would be 'SanderSchaeffer'?

Or bottom-line: How do I reply to a user with NodeRed? :)

<sup>*Apologies for the inconvenient title, but I don't know the name of this way of information output*</sup>

Comment: Are you asking how to read the properties of an object? Or is it not proper JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Node-RED Switch node to filter.

You can set it to act on the `msg.payload` value and use the **contains** option and then enter the text you want to match on into the box.

This should only allow Tweets which match through. You then probably want to use a function node to craft a suitable response.

EDIT:

To get just the sending user id then you would access it from within the function node as follows:

```
msg.tweet.user.screen_name
```

Comment: Huh.. How does this filter the users screen name (@<user>)? I just need to be able to tweet back to users who tweet 'x'. Now I only tweet what I want, without the user in the reply.

Comment: Remains 'undefined'. No matter I try `msg.payload.User`, `msg.payload.name` or `msg.payload.screen_name`

Comment: In that case I suggest you post your flow to the mailing list so people can have a proper look https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Comment: don't know why, but indeed msg.tweet.user.screen_name did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var myOutput = '"User": "SanderSchaeffer", "Tweet": "This is my tweet", "date": "01-02-2015"';
var parse = JSON.parse('{'+myOutput +'}');
var userName = parse.User;
```

Comment: No need to parse the data again, the Node-RED msg.payload value already is a JSON object

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a built in function to convert JSON data to a JavaScript Object. You can then access the JSON variables as an attribute of the object.

Just use the following code to parse the JSON to javascript:

```
var text = JSON code you retrieved;
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

You can then use the variable data by accessing them through the object:

```
document.write(obj.User);
document.write(obj.Tweet);
document.write(obj.date);
....
```

More information can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp
Which also explains how to access an array of JSON objects.

Comment: No need to parse the data again, the Node-RED msg.payload value already is a JSON object

Comment: Than the second part of the answer still applies. You should be able to retrieve the data as if it was a normal javascript object with certain attributes.

Comment: Not from within Node-RED, There is nowhere where document.write would be appropriate,